# Install linux manpages on macOS

Tags: command-line

I have to regularly work with Linux machines that don't have man installed (don't ask me why). Is it possible to install Linux man pages on macOS? I'm thinking about help for commands like `ip` or `ipset`, or perhaps GNU variants of common Unix tools. I've been using manpages.me, but it's quite cumbersome as it's not as responsive as a command line tool and also defaults to displaying FreeBSD manpages.

Comment: You would still need to access macOS man pages as well, so there would be a lot of conflicts. Maybe install a small Linux VM?

Comment: A VM seems extremely overkill and more cumbersome that using some online man service. I think I could avoid the conflicts by setting -M in an alias. I think I'l just download the manpages manually and put them somewhere, I was hoping for an easier solution.

Comment: What about https://ss64.com/bash/

Comment: Philippe: Which Linux would you desire to copy the manpages from? Including the version would be helpful. Also, which version of macOS would you be using?

Comment: I'd reference the [Linux man-pages project](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/index.html) via your web browser.

Comment: An essential question when you're a sysadmin, writing scripts that need to run on both macOS/BSD and GNU/Linux. That said, the [Heirloom Project](https://heirloom.sourceforge.net/)'s man pages are a useful reference if you're wanting to know what is the "lowest common denominator" functionality supported by, say, `find` or `grep` on Mac/BSD and Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

- Go to your Linux machine of choice and tar/zip the whole `/usr/share/man` directory.
- Copy the archive to your Mac and uncompress it, say into `~/Documents/linux-man`.
- Use the `-M` switch to make `man` search in that folder: `man -M ~/Documents/linux-man ip`
- Create a shell alias, function, or wrapper script for more convenient use. For example: `lman() { man -M ~/Documents/linux-man "$@" }`. Then you can do `lman 7 ip`.

Answer (score 0):

The recommendations to use man7.org and ss64.com are legit. I use both sites on a regular basis.

But I'm usually wanting to read man pages *in the terminal*, so I recently went looking for a semi-complete repository of GNU/Linux man pages in raw roff format, thinking I could `groff -T utf8` them on-the-fly.

I came up with a few options:

- [Debian Manpages](https://manpages.debian.org)
- the cgit instance for the [Linux man-pages project](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/docs/man-pages/man-pages.git)
- the cgit instance for the [POSIX man pages on kernel.org](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/docs/man-pages/man-pages-posix.git)

Here's an example of a Bash function which fetches the requested manual page from the Debian Manpages server, then typesets it with `groff`.

```bash
# fetch Debian Linux man pages from https://manpages.debian.org
lman() {
    local encoding=utf8
    local lang=en
    local baseurl='https://manpages.debian.org/stable'
    local manpage=${1:?What manual page do you want?}

    curl -sL "$baseurl/$manpage.$lang.gz" \
      | groff -man -T$encoding \
      | less
}
```

I have a recent `groff` from MacPorts, but the one that comes with macOS *should* be sufficient.

On my system, that produces an 80-column output. If you want to get fancy, here's how you can adjust the output to a specific number of columns (`maxwidth`), and center within the terminal. This greatly improves readability when your main display can show a lot of columns.

```bash
# fetch Debian Linux man pages from https://manpages.debian.org and reformat
# to `maxwidth` columns, centered within the terminal
lman() {
    local maxwidth=100
    local encoding=utf8
    local lang=en
    local baseurl='https://manpages.debian.org/stable'
    local termwidth=$(tput cols)
    local width=$(( termwidth < maxwidth ? termwidth : maxwidth ))
    local margin=$(( (termwidth - width) / 2 ))
    local pad=$(printf "%${margin}s")
    local manpage=${1:?What manual page do you want?}

    curl -sL "$baseurl/$manpage.$lang.gz" \
      | groff -man -T$encoding -rLL=${width}n \
      | sed "s/^/$pad/" \
      | less
}
```

The functions above aren't perfect, because of course the rendered man pages aren't cached so there's always a delay, and they don't differentiate between sections of the manual, *e.g.*, `crontab(1)` vs. `crontab(5)`. Implementing those features are left as an exercise for the reader. `;)`

To fetch from one of the other sources mentioned above, such as the POSIX man pages from kernel.org, just adjust the URL fetched by `curl` as required. For example, the roff source for the POSIX `cp` man  page can be fetched from https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/docs/man-pages/man-pages-posix.git/plain/man-pages-posix-2017/man1p/cp.1p, so you'd update the `lman` function like so:

```bash
# fetch a POSIX man page from git.kernel.org's man-pages repository
pman() {
    local encoding=utf8
    local baseurl='https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/docs/man-pages/man-pages-posix.git/plain/man-pages-posix-2017/man1p'
    local manpage=${1:?What manual page do you want?}

    curl -sL "$baseurl/$manpage.1p" \
      | groff -man -T$encoding \
      | less
}
```

[DarkDust's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/427413/324784) is still the best if you need offline access, though.

Comment: That's more or less the script I ended up writing myself. 